# Does uninstalling a program remove PATH variable leading to its folders?

Tags: environment-variables, path, uninstall

If a program addes a new PATH variable, once uninstalled does it remove it from the PATH?

Answer (score 0):

> If a program addes a new PATH variable, once uninstalled does it
>   remove it from the PATH?

The only way this would happen is if the uninstaller was designed to do so.

[DNX](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx) is what you installed, it is connected to ASP.NET and DNVM, which have been replaced by [.NET CLI](https://github.com/dotnet/cli)

> There is a path C:\Users\Marko.dnx\bin in my PATH variable. I checked
>   the folders only to see that .dnx folder doesn't exist.

This means the uninstaller did not edit the path variable.

> I never installed anything like it so I don't know if the program was
>   supposed to unistall it.

Based on the evidence I have found, I believe you have, simply forgotten what you installed.

Comment: The links in this answer, are links to Github repositories, there is nothing to quote.